# How to access the tokenized value in Java

Tags: java

I have tokenized string, I want to access the 1st,2nd,3rd value from it.

Can anyone look into this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code

```
String cssvalue = webDriver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).getCssValue("color");
String s = cssvalue;
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",() ");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

    log.info("TOken: "+st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are seeing with your current code ?

Comment: I don't think that ",() " is the correct token.

Comment: Its  output is 
TOken: rgba
TOken: 73
TOken: 151
TOken: 117
TOken: 1

I want to access the 73, 151, 117 value

Comment: is the result going to be similar at all times ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
String cssvalue = webDriver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).getCssValue("color");
String [] s = cssvalue.split("rgb");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s[1], ",() ");
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int index=0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
  values.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
  log.info("TOken: "+values.get(index));
  index++;

}
Integer [] a = values.toArray(new Integer[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the problem is still there, I want to access the values which are being tokenized?? How Will I be able to do that?

Comment: yeah, Whatever I will type-cast it later. But I want to access these vales at any possible condition

Comment: Ritesh: I also want to store the .hasMoreToken vales in array and I want to access them later as well... How I would be able to do that?

Comment: Zain: Does it answers all your query or something more you needed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have to store the first 3 tokens :

```
String cssvalue = webDriver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).getCssValue("color");
String s = cssvalue;
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",() ");
ArrayList<String> rgb_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    rgb_lst.add(st.nextToken());
    if (rgb_lst.size() == 3) break;
}
```

Or something similar.

Then you can get rgb_lst[0], rgb_lst[1] and rgb_lst[2].

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun because I think storing .hasMoreToken values is pointless :

```
String cssvalue = webDriver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).getCssValue("color");
String [] s = cssvalue.split("rgb");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s[1], ",() ");
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Boolean> more = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
Boolean b;
while (b = st.hasMoreTokens()) {
  values.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
  more.add(b); 
  log.info("TOken: "+values.get(values.size()-1));
}
```